# How to copy data based on count in range?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build in the following code in order to count  how many cells in a row have data. Based on the count I then need to Copy cells by the same number as the count. For instance if the count was 3 then I need to copy the data 3 times.

n = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:P2").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

The data to be copied three times would be located in Sheet1 A2:B2 and needs to be copied to Sheet2 A2:B2 
I would need to continue this until I reach an empty row in sheet1
Many thanks for any help or assistance.

Comment: What does "Copy three times" mean. How could the count of cells in `A2:B2` be three? What does `C2:P2` have to do with this? Can you share some sample data and explain a little clearer. The site `ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/` will help format data (choose excel after pasting your sample data in the top box) in a way that can be pasted here nicely.

Comment: I am counting the number of cells that contain data in the range C2:P2, based on that result I need to copy what ever text that is in A2:B2

Comment: The 'three times" was just an example of the result of the count

Comment: OK. But then "Copy it three times". You say you want to copy it into `Sheet2!A2:B2`. How can you copy something that is two cells into a range that is two cells... .three times.

Comment: Would it go into `A2:B2`, then `A3:B3`, then `A4:B4`. Then when we read the next row in `Sheet1` we start pasting however many times into `A5:B5`.. etc?

Comment: You are correct, if i need to copy three times then the text should then copy into A2:B2, A3:B3 and A4:B4. Hope this explains it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you will want to loop through each row that contains data in Sheet1. You will then want to count the number of populated columns in `C:P` through that row. Then paste that for however many times into Sheet2.

This will look something like:

```
Sub duplicateData()
    Dim rngReadRows As Range
    Dim rngWrite As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim timesToPaste As Integer
    Dim pasteCount As Integer
    Dim arrMonth() As Date


    'Set up the rows that we will read from
    Set rngReadRows = Sheet1.Range("A2:A10").Rows

    'Set up the first cell/row we will write to
    Set rngWrite = Sheet2.Range("A2")



    'Now loop through each row from which we will read
    For Each rngReadRow In rngReadRows.Rows

        'figure out how many times we need to paste this thing
        timesToPaste = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngReadRow.Offset(, 2).Resize(1, 13))

        'redim the date array to the size we need
        ReDim arrMonth(1 To timesToPaste)

        'Fill the array
        i = 1
        For Each rngCell In Sheet1.Range("C1:P1").Cells
            If rngReadRow.Cells(1, rngCell.Column).Value <> "" Then
                arrMonth(i) = rngCell.Value
                i = i + 1
            End If

        Next rngCell

        'Loop however many number of times
        For pasteCount = 1 To timesToPaste

            'Paste it
            rngReadRow.Resize(1, 2).Copy Destination:=rngWrite

            'Get the date
            rngWrite.Resize(1, 1).Offset(, 2).Value = arrMonth(pasteCount)

            'Increment to next row
            Set rngWrite = rngWrite.Offset(1)
        Next pasteCount
    Next rngReadRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Thnaks and this makes sense to an amateur like me. However geting a runtime error 424 at Set rngWrite = Sheet2.Range("A2")

Comment: So.. here I'm using the codename of the worksheets. IN VBE insure that you have the View>>Project Explorer pane open. You can see the `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` name of each Tab name (the tab name is the part in the parentheses) the code name is the part outside. Sometimes if you have deleted tabs and saved and all that you'll see `Sheet23 (Sheet2)` or something silly like that. So tab name "Sheet2" is actually codename `Sheet23`. Change as needed. I'm suspecting you don't have a `Sheet2` codename in your workbook.

Comment: You are correct I just had to change to Sheet3 in your code! When I now run it shows no errors but what seems to be happening is that it seems to be counting all rows rather than just one row at a time as the total number of populated columns I have in my test sheet is 11 and it seems to copy the data in A2:B2 11 times rather than just the three times which is the total number of populated colums for row A2

Comment: Oh yea... I totally goofed that up. One sec and I will fix.

Comment: Switched up the `for each` loop to iterate `.Rows`. Also switched the `rngReadRow.Resize(1, 2).Copy` to refer to the correct variable.. totally hosed that. Should be working now, just have to flip out your sheet numbers again.

Comment: Works fantastic - thank you so much. For my own learning, why do we only read from Sheet1.Range("A2:A10").Rows? Also I have an additional task I need to do to this but I will try some more based on what i have learned from you. Thanks again!

Comment: That is another line of code you will have to change. Change `A10` to whatever row your data ends on. I just put it at 10 to test so my computer wasn't chugging rows that weren't populated.

Comment: i could try a find last row perhaps?

Comment: Absolutely. That would definitely be my next step if this were my code.Something like `lastRow = Sheet1.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row`. Then..  `Set rngReadRows = Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Rows`

Comment: Perfect Genius! This might be difficult but is it possible to add this? Currently in Sheet1 C1:P1 contains dates, can we search in C2:P2 to see if there is any text and if there is can we copy the date from C1:P1 that corresponds with the column where the text was found in C2:P2. For instance if text was found in Cell C2 and Cell D2 then can we copy the dates from C1 and D1 into Sheet2 in cells C1 and C2 and so on moving onto search C3:P3 and copy dates into Sheet2   underneath the last copied data in Column C until we meet an empty row?

Comment: @JohnMc I've updated the code to bring in the column headers. Probably there is a cleaner way of doing this, but this will get you in the ballpark. If you have any other things you are trying to work through, please open a new question. You'll probably get faster responses since it won't be just me looking at it.